# How to change the height of dijit.layout.ContentPane in dijit.layout.AccordionContainer

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout, accordionpane

I want to have height set to AUTO for all my content panes in my dojo accordion. But it is currently taking the def height or the height i set for the accordion. 
does anyone know how to set the height of a content pane to dynamic or auto inside the dijit.layout.accordionpane.

Here is my sample code.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" id="@getId("Accordion")" duration="80" style="width: 760px; height:auto;">

   <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="@getId("InfoPane")" selected="true"    
      title="Basic Information">                
   </div>        

   <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="@getId("ContactPane")" title="Contact    
        Information">
   </div>
</div>
```

Please advice.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1364140 and dojox.widget.TitleGroup.

Comment: Yes. But this only works with Title group. We are using Dojo 1.6 and we have Accordion on almost all of our application pages. We cannot spend time in changing this to Title group.

Comment: Did you figure out an answer for this in the end. I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Yes i did. Use doLayout parameter for Accordion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the doLayout parameter of Accordion.

With this all the ContentPane's height will be set to their content instead of the Accordion height.